# Does jQuery's `click()` method work on hidden form elements?

Tags: jquery, forms, hidden-field

Or, asked another way, do hidden form elements (`<input type="hidden"... />`) support [jQuery's `click()` method](http://api.jquery.com/click/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, hidden inputs work with the `click()` method. You can't click on a hidden input element with your mouse, but you can execute the click event using the click method.

So, given this HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="input1" id="input1" value="Yes">
</form>
```

You can assign a click handler:

```
$('#input1').click(function () {
    //do something
});
```

and invoke the click event:

```
$('#input1').click();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/v6LUd/ for a working example.